# How can I bulk import articles and images in WordPress?

Tags: html, xml, wordpress, import, export

before advising me to use the import tool or a plugin: WAIT! I give you more details.

I'm working on a HUGE website. My goal is to move something like 1500 articles from one WordPress installation to another brand new website. I managed to import all the articles easily; at least, all the verbosity. I NEED to have the images too.

This is what I've done so far:

1. First, I copied all the wp-content/uploads (via FTP) from Website1-> Website2. Now I have a perfect copy of the wp-contents/uploads in both the WordPress installation. Of course, **I don't have** these images on my Website2's media library, yet.
2. I thought: maybe I can export an XML file from Website1 with all the articles and editing it before importing it on the Website2. I changed each line with Notepad++ from **domain.org/installation1/wp-content/uploads/ to domain.org/installation2/wp-content/uploads/**. This method FAILED. I have the articles, but not the images inside them. When I check on the front-end I get

```
<img src="">
```

like if WordPress didn't accept the image source.

3. Then I think: maybe I need to have all the images in my media library **before importing the articles**. So I tried in two different ways.
4. **3A.**. I tried with the import tool. I exported an XML file again from Website1 (selecting "Media") and edited again it changing the location from **domain.org/installation1/wp-content/uploads/ to domain.org/installation2/wp-content/uploads/**, because remember: I'm building the new website from scratch and I need two working on a new installation. Well, I tried few times but every time WordPress failed to import the images in the library.
5. **3B**. I tried with a plugin ("Add From Server"). This one managed to import some images (I tried with a single month) but it failed with the most. Now I just have like the 20% of the images in a single folder (like wp-contents/uploads/2021/01).

Please help me! There are something like 30000 photos and I definitely can't do it manually. Just a clarification:

- I would like to avoid the installation of a new plugin in Website1 because this site is running on an old version of WordPress and most of the plugins don't officially support old versions.
- I'm not a WordPress guru and I don't know so much about coding. Please forgive me if a said something nonsense.

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you zip all the data through cPanel and upload it on the new website? I personally believe this is a way more easier method, you just need to zip the files from file manager and then export database from the phpmyadmin.

Comment: As you cannot install new plugins in Website1, this to me sounds like you need to write a bit of custom code that will export the products in a XML feed. For website2 I would then recommend something like `WP All Import pro` (you will need the pro version for WooCommerce plugin) this plugin can also handle inline `img` tags and convert them to the corret url / source.

Comment: Thank you both! But you think that's it's just a matter of having the images in the library? Once I have them I can just import the articles and everything will be just fine?